# Looking for some good practices for Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I've been playing with Vagrant and Puppet and would like to set up the environment that the team and I can use. I'm not having technical problems with Vagrant, everything is clear and working there, but I do have some logical issues:

1. Everyone recommends one box per project. Is this really necessary? We do multiple projects with the same stack of software. I really don't see why we should not keep all projects in one box. Also, it would be very hard to switch back and forth between projects when we're doing maintenance and bug fixes.
2. How do you handle databases? We're working with MySQL db. How can we ensure that we do not have to import .sql files every time I 'vagrant up' a new box? Or do I just keep my box suspended, and not destroy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both questions sort of depends on your use case:

1. if your project are closely related, say they are all wordpress development, then sure 1 box would be enough. but for project that require different codebase, env support, you should be able to write simple puppet modules that enables you to quickly `vagrant up` a new box in minutes.
2. not sure about your use case, but even when you `vagrant halt`, database in mysql still be there when you fire `vagrant up` the next time. if you are talking about `vagrant destroy`, then you should be able to use a puppet script to import on new box creation (ie. `vagrant init`). check puppet's document on `File` and you will see how you may copy a .sql file into vagrant and run mysql import.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a connection for a MySQL server from host from a server?

Comment: Thanks for the answer bitinn, those were my guesses. As for the second question, I was thinking about doing what Dr. Java asked. I'm guessing it is possible to do this, but that means that I'm again depending on my local machine for development and the whole point of using Vagrant is lost

Comment: @MarkoLekić as long as you don't disable network on vagrant, this should be possible. a solution would be to create a vagrant box specifically for database, and let your team setup connection to it. note that you may need some port forwarding solution to allow remote access to a host's vagrant vm.